# Any reason to use Event over List<Object> for a simple pub/sub class?

Tags: c#, events, publish-subscribe

The second approach is simple, you keep a list of `subscribers`, and call them when the publisher post a message.

```
for (int i = 0; i < subscribers.Count; i++)
{
    var subscriber = subscribers[i] as IHandleMessage<T>;
    subscriber.Handle(message);
}
```

Is there any good reason why I should use Event/Delegate to implement this class?

Comment: Well for starters you won't need to write all the code to handle the lists of delegates if you use an `event`. You don't show your code to handle adding to the list in your example... But there's an obvious race condition if you have multiple threads involved because `subscribers.Count` could change between you checking it and accessing `subscribers[i]`. If you use `event`, such things are handled for you.

Comment: I think the question should be "Is there any reason to use a custom solution instead of using `event`?". And for your example, the answer would be "no".

Comment: But if you don't want to expose event name, eg. you want to only expose `subscribe` `unsubscribe` `publish`, do you not have to write more code to differentiate types of event anyway?

Comment: And event doesn't magically give me async callback anyway.

Comment: It does give you async callback (if raised on a different thread), but it doesn't give you *synchronous* callback (which is what I expect you meant). But events do give you threadsafe subscription and unsubscription.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, an event is a simplified Observer Pattern
And events are more flexible because you don't have to create a class that implements IHandleMessage for every action.